# Shuffling $\omega$ fairly for a fixed partition

Tags: co.combinatorics, infinite-combinatorics, partitions

Let ${\frak P}\subseteq {\cal P}(\omega)$ be a partition such that every block $B\in {\frak P}$ contains at least two integers.

Is there a countable set ${\cal F}$ of bijections $\varphi:\omega\to\omega$ such that given any two integers $a\neq b\in\omega$ there is exactly one $\varphi_{a,b}\in {\cal F}$ such that $\varphi_{a,b}(a)$ and $\varphi_{a,b}(b)$ belong to the same block $B\in{\frak P}$?

Comment: say, if there are only two blocks: $\{1,2\}$ and (everything else), one bijection is not enough, but for two bijections there exist two (and even infinitely many) elements which are mapped to the huge block in both.

Comment: Isn't this question the same as your question last autumn? https://mathoverflow.net/q/433364/1946 I answered there affirmatively if there are infinitely many blocks.